# How to protect my RESR Api calls in Flutter?

Tags: node.js, flutter, flutter-in-app-purchase, api-security

I am developing an app in flutter which will have in app purchases. I am keeping track of user credits and some other things on my node server.

I am concerned that if I call my node api to increase user credits in my app code, it can be accessed by decompiling the apk. I don't know how to call my api securely and protect it.

I am currently calling my api simply from my app.I read that an app's source code can be accessed by decompiling the APK? If that is the case then my code can be altered to call my node server without the in app purchases.

I don't know if it is even possible or not or if this is even a concern. I don't know much about security because I am still a student. If anyone can guide me, I would appreciate it greatly. Thanks!

Comment: There are many ways of secure a communication, but security is mainly handled by the backend to confirm users, not Apps. Using 2FA or OAuth2, tokenize calls, asymetric API Keys, and a bunch of good practices more.  Also, if you're using your app for payments, you can use a third party payment gateway that can secure that part. And finally, If someone can decompile your APK and see your code, how could they access to your customers' cards data or deploying the malicious code into your source?

Comment: Thank you for informing me about the different types of API protection methods. Actually, I am not concerned about someone getting access to user's card information as that is unlikely to happen unless there is an attack on my server. I meant it in a way that if someone modifies the code.
Like if a user is suppose to get 1000 credits after making the payment, I am concerned that they can get a lot more creds from just a single payment if they can modify the source code.

Comment: Think of your app as a mainly UI in those use cases, you ALWAYS need to have a double check in the backend of the transaction, and try to make all transaction logic in backend too. So, for instance: Mod Flutter App sends 100 USD, Backend saves 1K Credits on user, it doesn't matter if Mod Flutter App is showing 100K credits, because the backend has the real value and logic of that transactions. App should limit to be UI, and not hold that logic.

Comment: Thanks man. I think I have a much clearer understanding of it now. Thank you for the help, I really appreciate it.